# Constructed Variable in Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression

I am performing a regression on one variable against a set of predictors. I am trying to test whether a certain variable (constructed by myself from 3 other variables) had a significant effect on the response.

Feasibly, the other three variables could have had an impact on the response by themselves. Therefore, I have run the regression with these variables included as if to "hold them constant".

On to the interpretation - if the constructed variable is significant, does the fact that I included the three variables that comprise this constructed variable allow me to use the significance as evidence that the constructed variable itself has an impact on the response?

There is a significant correlation between the constructed variable and one of its constituents. Both of them are significant in the regression. Does this change the answer to the question above?

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of results should be deeper then a 'yes/no' answer in such cases.

Say, an epidemiological study might use $weight$, $height$ and $BMI$ ($weight/height^2$) as three predictors in a regression model of heart disease. It finds that $BMI$, but not the other two, has a significant effect. Would you claim that "*person's weight has no impact on heart disease*"? But clearly, it does determine the BMI, and can be strongly correlated with it?
Instead, I would phrase the conclusion along the lines of "*after adjusting for BMI, the linear effect of weight alone was not significant*", and focus on interpreting *why* the variables need to be combined in that particular way. But more detailed phrasing and discussion depends entirely on your field knowledge.

(additional note regarding composites: it is easy to fiddle with their construction until something significant comes out, so generally they are frowned upon in epidemiology, at least.)

Comment: Thank you for this - the field in question is economics.